# .Click after .append(<input type="button") does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've un problem with an .append with jQuery where i generate an input type button. I want to put an event on the button who from to the .append . Do you think that it is possible ?

I show you the code :

```
$('#MatchSeason').append("<tr><td>" + ui.item.label + "</td>" +
                         "<td id=" + 'Id' + " style=" + 'display:none' + ">" + ui.item.value + "</td>" +
                         "<td id=" + 'GroupingId' + " style=" + 'display:none' + ">" + ui.item.GroupingId + "</td>" +
                         "<td id="+'btnDeleteCell'+"><input type="+'button'+" id="+'btnDelete'+" name="+'btnDelete'+" value="+'Supprimer'+" </td>"+"</tr>"
                        )    


$('#btnDelete').click(function () {
            alert('test') 
});
```

Thanks for the answers !

Comment: Please include your HTML

Comment: Yes. I do think it is possible.

Comment: Yes. However as it stands you are not closing the `<input>` tag.

Comment: How does your actual code look like? Are the two snippets located exactly like that? FYI, there is no need for string concatenation if you know the string values.

Comment: With the markup including `<tr>`s, are you appending this content multiple times? If so, that will create multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid. IDs should be unique throughout the document and `$('#btnDelete')` will only find the 1st.

Comment: i've just closed the input but it change nothing, i try the next response and it works !

Comment: Yes, Jonathan i will create a class for these buttons

Comment: Next, provide a *complete* example of your code. As it is posted now, there is no reason why binding the handler shouldn't work (besides typos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$(document).on('click','#btnDelete',function () {
      alert('test') 
});
```

or

```
$('#MatchSeason').on('click','#btnDelete',function () {
      alert('test') 
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this?

Comment: Use this method, so the event will delegate properly.

Comment: With the statement order in the question, the element should exist for a direct binding to succeed.

Comment: not true. take a read here to understand. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The second solution works good thanks !

Comment: @eg_dac: not sure who you are addressing, but the code, as posted, would append the new content *before* the handler is bound. In this case event delegation is not needed.

Comment: i think it's a better habit to get into. providing delegates should be a standard.